# No desktop screen to navigate

Tags: ubuntu, desktop-environment

I was trying to install a new desktop interface on my ubuntu 17 system and it went fine. I rebooted and realised i already had unity,KDE and cinnamon desktop.

I thought of trying unity first and chose it on the login page. The system now shows a blank black screen and i dont seem to be able to reach the screen where i can choose another desktop.

Any suggestions how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

take a look in

```
/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-ubuntu.conf
```

for changing default session

Comment: How can i access the terminal ? Would i need the live cd?

Comment: To start Ubuntu into safe mode (Recovery Mode) hold down the left Shift key as the computer starts to boot. If holding the Shift key doesn't display the menu press the Esc key repeatedly to display the GRUB 2 menu. From there you can choose the recovery option. Then you can use the terminal to apply any changes

Comment: Lemme try this...

Comment: Unfortunately i am still locked out. I installed KDE and updated the 50-ubuntu.conf file however there is nothing after kubuntu logo flashes. Any other ideas? cant we clear all desktops and install one ?

Comment: Follow this thread to remove all desktop environments https://askubuntu.com/questions/181356/how-to-delete-all-desktop-environments-except-unity